# Failing to open Binary File

Tags: c++, file-io

3 File I/O streams are globally declared( outside all functions )

```
ifstream fin;
ofstream fout;
fstream file;
```

These are 2 functions where problem occurs. Due to some reason the file "quizquestions.dat" is unable to be opened. Due to which the statement exit(1); is being executed and the program is terminating. The question number is not being allotted properly.  The object "universal" is an object of my class question which stores the question.
The code gets compiled and there are no errors.

```
void questionnumber()
{
    int file_size=0;
    fin.open("quizquestions.dat",ios::in|ios::binary);
    fin.seekg(0,ios::end);
    file_size = file.tellg();
    if(file_size==0)
        universal.assignquestion(1);
    fin.close();
    int next_question = (file_size/sizeof(question)) + 1;
    universal.assignquestion(next_question);
}
void addquestion()
{
    ch='y';
    do
    {
        cout<<"Adding question now\n";
        cout<<"Please\n";
        universal.createquestion();
        questionnumber();
        fout.open("quizquestions.dat",ios::app|ios::binary);
        if(!fout)
            exit(1);
        fout.write((char*)&universal,sizeof(question));
        fout.close();
        cout<<"Your question is added\nYour question details are as follows"<<endl;
        universal.dispquestion();
        cout<<"Do you want to add more questions?(Y/N)\n";
        cin>>ch; cin.ignore();
    }
    while(ch=='y'||ch=='Y');
    if(ch!='y'||ch!='Y')
        dispsetting();
}
```

Comment: are you sure the file exists on the location where your compiled exe is present??  you should also try ios::out in the flags

Comment: Even if it didn't existed, wouldn't a new file be created with same name?

Comment: why are you making a check if(!fout).. you must check !fout_isopen() function.

Answer (score 0):

try using fout.open(ios::app | ios:binary | ios::out);